# Compiling C code inside a C++ code inside a Objective-C++ code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c++, llvm-3.0

My problem is a little complex:

**Library:**
I have a library written in C and C++. It compiles perfecly in XCode with Apple LLVM.
The work of this library itself is done by the C code while the C++ part is just a C++ interface because I prefer C++. In theory I need to use only C++ to comunicate with it.

**The application:**
I have an application in Objective-C that uses the library above. Of couse, as the communication with my library is done via C++ I need to have a .mm file in order to call my library from "Objective-C++".

During the compilation... several issued of "C" languages happen:

- error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line
- error: statement expression not allowed at file scope
- etc...

It only happens with Objective-C++

- Objective-C++ (app) -> C++ headers (lib) -> C headers (lib, with extern "C") -> **NOT OK!!! WHY?**

If I make another C++ application for test of library, it goes ok

- C++ (app) -> C++ (lib) -> C header (lib, with extern "C") -> **OK**

*Detail: I am always using the Apple LLVM compiler here*

**The question:**
How do I compile C code from C++ from Objective-C++ code? Why it's different than compile from a regular C++ code?

Comment: I have seen very little that won't work but there are things that are different.  For instance you can't have anything named `id` or `SEL` in your code because that would resolve to something special in Objective-C++.  Can you give more specifics (e.g. the exact contents of the line that triggers the "non-const static data member" error)?

Comment: Have you tried to set the file type of the library to C++ source file? I had problems before because of this. You nee to select that file in XCode , go to the File Inspector (alt + cmd + 1) and select the file type.

Comment: George, the File inspector recognizes my file .mm as Objective-C++... so it's right. Thank you

Comment: Kevin, the line: `typedef struct __tag_LIGHT_CONTEXT { char data[__CB_DECL( LIGHT_CONTEXT_LEN )]; } LIGHT_CONTEXT; throws the error... being #define __CB_DECL(x) (x) and #define LIGHT_CONTEXT_LEN MAX( LEFT_LIGHT_LEN, RIGHT_LIGHT_LEN )`

Comment: I'd bet the `MAX` is the problem.  Objective-C/Cocoa defines this macro (`NSObjCRuntime.h` in `Foundation.framework`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of tries and Google I finally could figure out.
Before I call my C headers, I should undefine MAX and MIN macros. For some reason they were previous defined. The compiler doesn't show the error with precision. That's why it was difficult. The C framework I am using has it's own declaration of MAX and MIN macros...

Another very interesting thing that might be useful for others is that before  we need to do the same thing: undefine max and min (lower case) if we are using some C framework that implements it's own max and min.

It solved both problems.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to do

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

<Some C method declaration>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

in your header files that contain C method declarations.